# Trying to create a dictionary of types

Tags: swift, dictionary, types

**I'm trying to create a dictionary of types** (all types conforming to CKRecordType). This wouldn't be a dictionary of different types of objects, but an actual dictionary of different objects' types (i.e. *I want to match all of the keys I'm using to save in a CKRecord field to the type of CKRecordValue that field stores*). **Is this possible in Swift?** All of the types are named types, but I'm not sure how I'd refer to them (is there a 'type' type).

I'm looking for something like this: `Dictionary<String, Type>` or `Dictionary<String, TypeIdentifier>` or `Dictionary<String, CKRecordValue.conformingTypes>` etc...

**EDIT**

This is the code I'm currently using (in a protocol):

```
static var dictionaryOfKeysAndAssociatedValueTypes: Dictionary<String, CKRecordType.Type> { get }
```

or

```
static var dictionaryOfKeysAndAssociatedValueTypes: [String: CKRecordType.Type] { get }
```

which generates a `"Use of undeclared type 'CKRecordType'"` with Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a way to do this: your `conformingTypes` actually exists, and it's called `Type`:

```
Dictionary<String, CKRecordValue.Type>
```

or

```
[String: CKRecordValue.Type]
```

Comment: I'm getting "Use of undeclared type..." error with that format. I'm pretty sure that's because CKRecordValue is a protocol...

Comment: I'm using this right now with a protocol in Xcode 8 beta 6. If you create an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) maybe I can help with that error.

Comment: I'll try updating, I'm running Xcode 7.3. Also put specific code in my last Edit.

Comment: I'm kinda excited (I've been putting off Swift 3, but this and sharing from privateDB will make things in my project a lot easier)

Comment: I was using CKRecordType.Type rather than CKRecordValue.Type. Eventually noticed that. Now I just have to figure out what the heck happened to CKErrorCode enums in the transition :(